# Python.exe stops working as soon as I import any PyQt5 module

Tags: python, crash, anaconda, python-import, pyqt5

I am working on a windows amd64 machine with all the latest anaconda packages; In an attempt to solve this problem I went and updated them all with conda update --all to be sure, but the issue is still present.

As I understand it, PyQt5 is included in the latest anaconda packages, but I haven't found many topics on similar issues, and the solutions I tried didnt work.
I tried running pyuic5 too, which comes included with anaconda and depends on PyQt, and it crashes python instantly.

Here's the output of conda list qt:

```
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py35_2
PyQt5                     5.8.2                     <pip>
qt                        5.6.2                    vc14_3  [vc14]
qtawesome                 0.4.4                    py35_0
qtconsole                 4.3.0                    py35_0
qtpy                      1.2.1                    py35_0
```

Comment: Can you include the output of the `conda list qt` command?

Comment: added it to the post

Comment: I see you have `pyqt` installed with conda but at the same time you have `PyQt5` installed with pip. These don't work together. I had [the same issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1554). You can try to update Python to 3.6 or completely reinstall your Anaconda distribution from scratch. I haven't found any other way to fix it. Make sure you don't use pip again to install PyQt in your Anaconda Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I reinstalled Anaconda and it seems to be working perfectly now.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351619/cannot-import-pandas-anaconda3-python-crashes-without-error-message/53104272#53104272

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Anaconda or in my case removing it solved the issue.

Confirmed @ win 10 x 64, python 3.6.1 , MiniAnaconda